# 'Unexpected Identifier' when using Electron with Parcel and Babel 7

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, babeljs, parcel

I'm building an Electron app with Parcel, using Babel 7.  Basically a modified version of [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@yogeshkumarr/production-ready-electron-app-using-react-and-parcel-web-bundler-74dcda63f148).

I'm using a basic .babelrc:

```
{ "presets": [
    ["@babel/env", {
      "targets": { "node": 7 },
      "useBuiltIns": true
    }],
    "@babel/react"
  ],
  "plugins": ["dynamic-import-node"]
}
```

This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "appName",
  "productName": "App Name",
  "version": "3.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "react-start": "parcel -p 3000 app.html --out-dir build",
    "react-build": "parcel build app.html --out-dir build --public-url ./",
    "clean-build": "rm -rf build/ .cache dist/",
    "build": "yarn clean-build && yarn react-build",
    "start": "concurrently \"cross-env NODE_ENV=development yarn react-start\" \"wait-on http://localhost:3000 && electron . \""
  },
  "main": "./src/main.js",
  "browserslist": "electron 1.6",
  "build": {
    "productName": "AppName",
    "appId": "org.company.AppName",
    "files": [
      "node_modules/",
      "app.html",
      "main.js",
      "package.json"
    ],
    "dmg": {
      "contents": [
        {
          "x": 130,
          "y": 220
        },
        {
          "x": 410,
          "y": 220,
          "type": "link",
          "path": "/Applications"
        }
      ]
    },
    "mac": {
      "target": "dmg",
      "icon": "build/icon.ico"
    },
    "win": {
      "target": "nsis",
      "icon": "build/icon.ico"
    },
    "linux": {
      "target": [
        "deb",
        "AppImage"
      ],
      "icon": "build/icon.ico",
      "category": "Development"
    },
    "directories": {
      "buildResources": "resources",
      "output": "release"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.4.4",
    "@react/react-spectrum": "^2.22.0",
    "babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node": "^2.3.0",
    "electron-devtools-installer": "^2.2.4",
    "electron-store": "^4.0.0",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.2.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.2.3",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.2",
    "babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node-babel-7": "^2.0.7",
    "concurrently": "^4.1.1",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "electron": "^6.0.0",
    "electron-is-dev": "^1.1.0",
    "electron-log": "^3.0.7",
    "eslint": "^6.1.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-compat": "^3.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.18.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.14.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^1.6.1",
    "parcel-bundler": "^1.12.3",
    "wait-on": "^3.3.0"
  }
}
```

When I run just the React (`react-build` and `react-start`), I get 0 compile problems and a happy app in the browser, when I run the Electron (`build` and `start`) I get the following from my `main.js` file.

```
 import path from 'path';
        ^^^^

 SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:722:23)
     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:798:10)
     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:645:32)
     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:560:12)
     at loadApplicationPackage (/Users/lipton/symposium/node_modules/electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Resources/default_app.asar/main.js:109:16)
     at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/lipton/symposium/node_modules/electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Resources/default_app.asar/main.js:155:9)
     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:786:30)
     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:798:10)
     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:645:32)
     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:560:12)
```

I've tried switching between `@babel/preset-env` and `@babel/env` (doesn't seem to matter).

I've tried tracking down the existing issue either in electron docs, or parcel docs, or babel docs.  I'm stumped.

UPDATE: Tried clearing out `node_modules` and reinstalling.  Error is in my renderer where I'm using ES6 import.  If I switch just the renderer to ES5 imports, it works.

Comment: Hey @jen. I am the author of the medium post. I am able to compile using your mentioned dependencies and dev-dependencies. Also used your version of babelrc. Can you just remove your node_modules folder, run yarn clean-build, re-install dependencies using yarn and let me know?

Comment: Where do you import path - renderer or main?

Comment: @yogeshhkumarr  I tried reinstalling node_modules.  A major place I divert from the tutorial I should have mentioned is that in electron.js (I call main.js, aka the renderer), I switch to ES6 style import.  If I switch back to ES5 it works.

Comment: @ford04, its in the renderer